# Ansible refer to another directory

Tags: linux, command-line, ansible, directory, path

I have the following structure:

- files
- ansible:

  - playbooks
  - templates
  - files

And my playbook.yml is inside playbooks folder:

```
  - name: "Write variable to file"
  vars:
    db_password: "{{ db_pass }}"
  template:
    src: templates/test.yml.j2
    dest: files/test.yml
```

But I cannot make it work, the error is :
"msg": "Could not find or access 'templates/test.yml.j2'
"msg": "Could not find or access 'templates/test.yml.j2'

How can I make my src and dest refer to files that are not in the same folder as playbook?

Comment: Pro tip: use the command `tree` to generate your files structure to show them in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `files` and `templates` folder isn't in the playbook directory, so you need to reference it like this:

```
  template:
    src: ../templates/test.yml.j2
    dest: ../files/test.yml
```

If I am mistaken, please send a better description of your folder structure.

Comment: If you move the playbook at the same level as the templates folder, you can actually references the template only with `test.yml.j2`